# How to resize a div without changing the position or order of other div

Tags: html, css

Can anyone help me, I want to overlay a div on another without changing the order or position of other div, I don't want to use position absolute because of the display inline blocks, can anyone give me idea of how to do it?
My HTML:

```
</div>
<div class="second-box">

</div>
<div class="third-box">

</div>
```

My CSS:

```
.first-box{
  background-color: blue;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
}
.second-box{
  background-color: yellow;
  display: inline-block;
  width:40px;
  height:40px;
}
.third-box{
  background-color: red;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
}
.first-box:hover{
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
}
```

The effect which i want is for a div to cover the other divs without changing its position
[image: The effect which i want]

Comment: It would be helpful to see what effect you're trying to achieve in order to give you the best advice. Can you share a design/screenshot of what you're after?

Comment: Can I know why don't you want to use position absolute in this case, you can do this with `position:absolute` other than using inline-block?

Comment: if i use position: absolute the yellow or other div beside it will take its position behind ex: imagine if i put like 5 different div next to blue (first-div) it will cover one of the div. which is not ideal and if i want to apply the same for any 5 of the divs then i need to check the position of the div which i hover and add margin to push it outside.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it i changed the CSS in this way

```
.first-box:hover{
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
  transform: scale(1.4,1.4) translate(5.5px, 5.5px);
}
```

now it works like i wanted to